# Rets Gem Syntax ruby/rails no_records_no_error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rets

I am using the [rets](https://github.com/estately/rets) gem to download real estate data.

I am trying to pass `:no_records_not_an_error` to the `find` command, but I can't get the syntax right:

```
:no_records_not_an_error => true
```

I've tried many different iterations using brackets, nested parentheses, with and without comma, but I have not been able to find the right syntax:

```
properties = client.find (:all, :no_records_not_an_error => true), {
  search_type: 'Property',
  class: klass,
  query: status_query,
  limit: 2000,
  offset: offset,
  select: columns_system.join(',')
}
```

This code DOES work without `no_records..`, but it breaks with an error at the very end when there are no search results.  I would like this code to return 0 or nil when there are no search results.

Comment: "it breaks with an error"? What error? We need to know that sort of information. Please provide a small piece of code we can run to generate the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you write it like this

```
properties = client.find (:all), {
  no_records_not_an_error: true,
  search_type: 'Property',
  class: klass,
  query: status_query,
  limit: 2000,
  offset: offset,
  select: columns_system.join(',')
}
```

Or you can simply remove no_records_not_an_error option and just write

```
properties.compact
```

This will remove all nil values in properties